# When binary searching what would you return if a number isn't in the array?

Tags: search, binary

For instance in the array {-2, 8, 13, 22, 25, 25, 38, 42, 51, 103} if I were to be given the number -1 to search what would binary search return? -1 right?

Edit: In java

Comment: Which programming language are you referring to? The implementation should be programming language dependent

Comment: Return ERROR, because you fail to find "-1" in the array.

Comment: Sorry i meant in java.

Comment: what do you return if you find the number? `1`, `0`, the position in the array, the number itself? for the first 3 possibilities `-1` is a good return value for not found.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your implementation.

You can indeed return a `-1`. If for example however, you are using a dynamic language, you can return a falsy value such as `false`, or you can even throw an exception when the value is not in your array.

Comment: What would it return in java?

Comment: @AznRiceBallz It depends. You can return a `-1`, `null`, or throw an `exception`

Comment: What about if you used binary search to look for 30 would it also return -1, null, or throw an exception?